# Android Studio: Upload Image From Android Studio To Cloudinary (https://cloudinary.com/)

Tags: php, android, android-networking, cloudinary

> Hello Pro.
>   I need to load image from Android Studio to Cloudinary but it don't
>   understand how to configure and the steps to execute this. I have read
>   the document on the web page:
>   https://cloudinary.com/documentation/android_image_and_video_upload
>   but not know must start from where. Please support my configuration.
>   Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the installation steps here: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/android_integration#installation
I will recommend installing and then try running the sample android project to make sure you have everything configured and running correctly.